# PDF image resizing on print

Tags: image, pdf, printing, barcode-printing

I have a bar-code image with dimensions 16x36 in my pdf.
The image is added to the PDF without any resizing and occupies 5.64mm x 12.70mm or 0.22inch by 0.5inches. This looks like the image in the PDF is treated as 72dpi as the actual image is 16x36 pixels 36/72 = 0.5 (height of image in PDF).

When the image is printed, it seems that the DPI of the printer causes re-sampling/resizing of the image which results in a barcode that is no longer readable by the scanner. The image below (printed at 300dpi) illustrates the top part of my 16x36 bar-code which has been reszied to 69 pixels in width meaning some of the bar-code matrix has been resized (16 won't go into 69) so some "columns" are 4 pixels, some 5 and one 6. So the bar-code is no longer readable.

[image: Top of barcode with stretch]


Is there any way to force the image to be printed without re-sampling/scaling?
I am using virtual printer emulators such as Raster Image Printer 10.0 and ImagePrinter Pro for my testing.

Comment: Please consider using a bar-code image at higher resolution (e.g. 160x360) and scale it to fit. That most likely won't result in such drastic differences. That been said, please provide a sample PDF to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using a bar-code image at higher resolution (e.g. 160x360) and scale it to fit. That most likely won't result in such drastic differences, not 4, 5, and 6 but 44, 45, and 46, i.e. merely slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Use a smaller printer, therefore you do not have to make the barcode bigger.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J88-RdWnNT0